# Overriding a magento controller

Tags: magento, controller, overriding

Im trying to override another extensions controller.

Config.xml

```
<config>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml_account>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Blizzardlabs_Adminhtmlext before="Magestore_Affiliateplus">Blizzardlabs_Adminhtmlext</Blizzardlabs_Adminhtmlext>                        
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml_account>
        </routers>
    </admin>    
</config>
```

Blizzardlabs/Adminhtmlext/controllers/Adminhtml/AccountController.php

```
include_once 'Magestore/Affiliateplus/controllers/Adminhtml/AccountController.php';

class Blizzardlabs_Adminhtmlext_Adminhtml_AccountController extends Magestore_Affiliateplus_Adminhtml_AccountController
{
    public function editAction() {
        die();
    } 
}
```

Yet when i go to the page that calls the code its not picking up my die()...please help!!

Comment: Hi Bill Garrison. I know it's been a while. How did you go with this problem? Did you manage to solve the problem? Because I am actually having the exact same problem as well and would like to know if there was indeed a solution to solve it. Cheers.

Comment: I'm sorry, if I figure out my issue I try and post it up here so if there is nothing it means I found nothing and went a different way. To be honest I can't remember which way I went with this so I apologize. Hope you have better luck then I did.